# Copy sections of a text file based on date

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble trying to copy just a portion of a log file that contains the same date for a given column. The columns do not have headers.

Here is an example of some lines of the

fax@email.com   {SMP}fax@email.com  RX  1234    18:00 06/26/14  0   F   001 1234567890

fax@email.com   {SMP}fax@email.com  RX  1234    19:01 06/26/14  0   F   001 1234567890

fax@email.com   {SMP}fax@email.com  RX  1234    20:02 06/26/14  0   F   001 1234567890

fax@email.com   {SMP}fax@email.com  RX  1234    21:03 06/26/14  0   F   001 1234567890

fax@email.com   {SMP}fax@email.com  RX  1234    01:04 06/27/14  0   F   001 1234567890

If I had those 5 lines of data, from the 6/26/14 date, I would like to copy those lines and export to a new file. Ignoring the line that is listed at 6/27/14 since it's not what I want.

The files export to a .log, not csv. They appear to be tab separated, however it's just a log file.

I thought I could take the avenue of Get-Content, possibly piped to a ForEach-Object (with an if statement to find the lines with identical dates).

Any ideas would help, thank you!

Comment: How big is this log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
get-content <file path> | foreach-object {if($_.contains("06/26/14")){$_ | out-file <newfilepath>.log -append}}
```

Comment: The **foreach** loop looks like overkill for this...just use **Select-String** or **-match**.

Comment: Also, **-Append** is redundant, since you're only invoking **Out-File** once (piping to **Out-File** invokes it once, as opposed to using it in a loop, in which case **-Append** would be required).

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options that you've got here. Easiest for something like that where you need a simple match in a text file is select-string:

```
Select-String -Path C:\Path\To\File.log -SimpleMatch "06/26/14" | Select -Expand Line | Out-File C:\Path\To\NewFile.log
```

If you need something more complex you could run it through a Get-Content/Where process, and even use a regex match if desired:

```
GC C:\Path\To\File.log | ?{$_ -match "06/26/14"}|Out-File C:\Path\To\NewFile.log
```

Or if you need to manipulate the data you can split it on the tabs, and create objects to add to an array. If you want to go that route just say so and I can help you with that process.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to select lines from the log file that contain `06/26/14` and copy them to another file, you can do it this way:

```powershell
Get-Content <path> | Select-String '06/26/14' | Out-File <path>
```

or this way:

```powershell
(Get-Content <path>) -match '06/26/14' | Out-File <path>
```